# Mocking a signed in Identity User

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I am using Moq and xUnit to create unit tests. However, because of the way my action methods are set up, I'm having a hard time doing so. In my controller, I use

```
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

to get the the signed in user information. I used this approach to avoid the number of parameters Is there a way to mock this in a unit test, or should the controller be set up differently?

The `AppUser` class extends `IdentityUser` for specific properties that are used within the controller.

Comment: You should use `AuthenticationManager.User.Name`. That way you can mock it during unit test.

Answer (score 0):

For mocking above you can do something like following,

```
Mock<UserManager<User>> userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<User>>();
userManagerMock
    .Setup(m => m.FindByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<User>()));
```

Please note I haven't compiled this code, but you should be able to get the idea.